# why url_for function doesnot generate a proper link

Tags: python, flask

I have the following url_for function which is supposed to generate url for the photo.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/items/{{i.filename }}') }}">
```

This is the actual output i get. and the only mistake is in the filename at the end, everything else is correct.

```
<img src="/static/img/items/%7B%7Bi.filename%20%7D%7D">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/items/'+i.filename)}}">
```